# accessing members of boost:: tuple

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to implement a vector like vector< boost::tuple<int,int,int> >day; I want to acess tuple's first element to check a condition.
can someone please tell me how to do it? I am new to boost.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector< boost::tuple<int, int, int> > v;
    v.push_back(boost::make_tuple(1, 2, 3));
    std::cout << boost::get<0>(v[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::get<1>(v[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::get<2>(v[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: if I dont use this make_tuple(), will I be able to use get<>()

Comment: @Shweta: yes, `make_tuple` is just a helper function to create a tuple.

Comment: your method is giving some errors, can it be version problem or something else. The error is error: ‘boost::get<0>’ is not a member of ‘boost::tuples::tuple<int, int, int, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>’

Comment: @Shweta then replace `v[0].get<n>()` with `boost::get<n>(v[0])`

Comment: thanxd it worked but why didnt it worked with the prevoius way. What are the differences?

Comment: It's the same, but the member `get` functions are not supported by every compiler : which compiler are you using ?

Answer (score 6):

First tupple has a set of types:
Edit (Fixed your post) But using abstract type here to demonstrate how it works better.

```
std::vector<boost::tuple<A, B, C> >   day;

// Load data into day;
```

Now you can extract that parts of the tupple using the get method.

```
A&   aPart = day[0].get<0>();
B&   bPart = day[0].get<1>();
C&   cPart = day[0].get<2>();
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `get<0>,get<1>,get<2>`?

Comment: Has anyone seen the error message that is generated when you access an invalid index?  Also, lack of a visualizer for VS is putting me off.