# Iterate over map<boost::tuple<int, string>, int> in C++

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, iterator, tuples

I have the following :

```
map<boost::tuple<int, string>, int> edges;
edges[boost::make_tuple(1, "a")] = 1;
```

A simple `cout << edges[boost::make_tuple(1, "a")] << endl;` confirms it to be 1;

How can I iterate over this?  The following doesn't seem to work :

```
typedef  map<boost::tuple<int, string>, int>::iterator it_type;
for(it_type i = edges.begin(); i != edges.end(); i++) {
     cout << i->first << endl;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `i->second`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i->first` is a `tuple`. Thus you can not just `cout` it.

Please see [accessing members of boost:: tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561605/accessing-members-of-boost-tuple) to know how to access a tuple.

You can use `i->second` as it is a `int`, and thus you can use `cout` using it.